# Blackgram leaves. SDS page. Phosphate buffer method

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins, gel-electrophoresis, sds-page

[image: Gel pic]
I am doing protein analysis in blackgram leaves by using phosphate buffer method. But I cannot get proper bands on my SDS-PAGE. What should I do to get proper bands?

Comment: Can you please exactly describe what you have done? At the moment this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should de-stain your gel longer. I can see at least one thick band at the top, but without de-staining longer you are probably missing other fainter bands.

Also, please explain what you mean by "proper bands". The top one looks fine to me. There might be others but we cannot see them.

Comment: There are other bands below; definitely destain. But perhaps the OP is referring to the frowning?

Comment: In protein analysis lots of bands can be seen in the gel bt I got only one band. That's why I am asking what should I do? Can you send a proper protocol to me. My mail I'd mohanlal0606@gmail.com. please help me by sending detailed protocol.. Thank you all for your comments..

Comment: @Mohanlal seeing a single band might be a good result, depending on what you are trying to achieve. For example, if your goal is to purify a protein, it's very good news when a single band shows up on an SDS-PAGE (assuming this is the correct protein, of course). I don't think you need to change anything to your electrophoresis protocol, except de-staining longer. You might need to change whatever you are doing before the SDS-PAGE if this single-band result is not what you want.